# Где корень в слове "стоишь"?

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте!

Я утверждаю, что в слове "стоишь" корень - "сто", а сын говорит, что учительница им сказала, что на гласную корень оканчиваться не может, только на согласную. И поэтому здесь корень "ст". А как же тогда однокоренные слова "стоять, стойка, стойло", ведь "общее" у все заканчивается на "о"?

Answer (score 3):

> учительница им сказала, что на гласную корень оканчиваться не может, только на согласную

Если так, то учительница неправа. Скорее всего, она или сын забыли "как правило" или что-то такое. Вообще утверждение можно в некотором считать справедливым разве что в плане исторической морфологии, да и то с огромными оговорками. Но в школе такие вещи не обсуждают.
Если же учительница действительно так считает, попросите её найти корень в слове "обувь". Сравните: "обуваться", "разутый" и проч. Интересно, какой корень она вычленит.

В отношении конкретного слова - тут сложнее. Если они уже знают о корневых чередованиях, то можно объяснить, что здесь чередование сто/ста(н) : стоять, вставать, стан, становиться и проч. Во всяком случае выделение корня "сто-" вполне правомерно с академической точки зрения. Но как к этому относится "школьная" русистика - сказать не могу, думаю, меня поправят, если что.

Comment: В качестве примера слова, корень которого оканчивается на гласную, можно взять и слово "дать". Наверное, и других примеров можно немало накопать

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

З.А Потиха в "Школьном словаре строения слов русского языка" выделяет корень сто-

Comment: Угу. Шанский - тоже. Но это неудивительно, удивительно, что учителка этого не знает.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли учительница это сказала. Мальчик скорее всего что-то напутал. Может, она говорила, что сокращать нельзя на гласный? Других подобных правил я не могу припомнить.

**В комментарий не поместилось, поэтому дополняю ответ.**
  А с чего вы взяли, что разбирался состав слова? На уроке речь могла идти о чём угодно. Может, делали морфологический разбор слова, где много сокращений (глаг.,  ед. ч.), а ребёнок написал стаишь. И пришлось попутно выделять в слове корень для проверки гласной. Внимание детей неустойчиво, мальчик мог в любой момент "отключиться" и у него в голове что-то перепуталась. Это один из возможных вариантов. Хотя, могло что-то перепутаться и в голове учительницы. Случается, что сейчас в школах преподают недавние выпускницы этих же школ, да ещё и далеко с невысшей оценкой по преподаваемому предмету. Словом, вариантов может быть много. А всерьз обсуждать, может ли корень оканчиваться на гласную, не стоит. Без вариантов - МОЖЕТ.

Comment: А с чего бы учительнице вспоминать о правилах сокращений, разбирая состав слова? Или Вы полагаете, что она сказала это в другой раз? Тогда и разбираться не стоит, проще попросить парня уточнить.

Comment: >А с чего вы взяли, что разбирался состав слова?  
  
Трудно предположить, что ребенок вспомнил некую фразу учительницы, произнесенную в другой ситуации и по другому поводу, и связал её с корнем слова "стоять". Я так так понял сам вопрос, что учительница конкретно поправила ученика. Но, повторюсь, если я ошибаюсь и всё это это - его фантазии, то спорить не о чем. Надо просто переспросить учительницу.

Comment: И ученик мог напутать, и учительница не знать. Хотя знать должна. Знаю только, что в начальной школе, когда разбираются простые слова, когда происходит первичное обучение морфемному разбору,некоторые учителя так говорят. Возможно, ученик перенес фразу из одной ситуации в другую. Не скажу, что согласна с "начальниками", но им видней, им вообще сложнее всех приходится.

Comment: Подозреваю, что уч-ца могла и напутать...Так как она однажды проставила красной пастой ударения над "ё" и в односложных словах и снизила сыну за это оценку:(

Comment: Какой это класс?

Comment: Это пятый класс.